# guardar valor en la BD mediante JQUERY: C# y ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, jquery, asp

Tengo como un formulario donde inserto valores que los guarda en la base de datos y los muestra en una tabla. Eso lo hace perfectamente. Bien, en la tabla tengo un desplegable en una de las columnas para poder modificar ese valor directamente desde la tabla, y no tener que borrar esa fila y volver a insertar todos los datos. Ese desplegable lo relleno de esta forma:

```
        DropDownList selectorDeportes = new DropDownList();

        selectorDeportes.ID = "seldep" + subscriptores[i].Nick;
        selectorDeportes.Attributes.Add("onchange", "GuardaDeporte('seldep" + subscriptores[i].Nick + "', " + i.ToString() + ");");
        selectorDeportes.Items.Add(new ListItem("Sin Equipo", "Sin Equipo"));
        for (j = 0; j < actual.m_lecEquiposDeporte.Count; j++)
            selectorDeportes.Items.Add(new ListItem(actual.m_lecEquiposDeporte[j].Deporte + "," + actual.m_lecEquiposDeporte[j].Genero + "," + actual.m_lecEquiposDeporte[j].Nombre, actual.m_lecEquiposDeporte[j].Codigo));
        if (subscriptores[i].Equipo.Length > 0)
            selectorDeportes.SelectedValue = subscriptores[i].Equipo;
        else
            selectorDeportes.SelectedIndex = 0;
        deportes = deportes + subscriptores[i].Equipo + "+";


        celda.Controls.Add(selectorDeportes);
        fila.Cells.Add(celda);
```

Eso también lo hace bien. Para guardarlo en la base de datos, tengo la siguiente funcion hecha en jquery, donde accede a esta función cuando cambias el valor deldesplegable.

```
     function GuardaDeporte(id_control, indice) {
         var almacen = $($("[id$='ValoresSeccion']")[0]);
         var codActuales = almacen.val();
         var nuevo = $($("[id$='" + id_control + "']")[0]);
         codActuales[indice] = nuevo.val();
         var acumulador = codActuales[0];
         for (i = 1; i < codActuales.length; i++)
             acumulador = acumulador + "+" + codActuales[i];
         almacen.val(acumulador);
     }
```

Por último para guardar el resultado en la base de datos, lo guardo de esta forma:

```
   string[] parti = new string[actual.m_ljcPlantillaJugadores.Count];

   for (i = 0; i < actual.m_ljcPlantillaJugadores.Count; i++)
    {
        actual.m_ljcPlantillaJugadores[i].Equipo = parti[i];
        actual.m_ljcPlantillaJugadores[i].Guardar();
    }
```

Guardar() es la función que lo inserta en la base de datos que sí funciona.

Que es lo que debe estar fallando? Con eso directamente no me inserta en la BD, pero otras veces si me ha insertado el valor pero solo la primera página. (hay un pagineo que expecifica el limite de filas por página y puedes ir cambianfdo de páginas con flechas).

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!!

PD: añado el código del método Guardar();

```
  public virtual void Guardar()
    {
      MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(m_strCadenaConexion);
    MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("update usuarios set usuario_principal=@codi  where nick=@id", conexion);

    conexion.Open();
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", nick);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codi", usuario_principal);
    comando.ExecuteScalar();

    conexion.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Dices que no inserta pero tu query  de guardado es solo para actualizar en donde esta la parte de insercion?

Comment: A ver, tal vez no me haya explicado bien. Lo que quiero hacer es solo actualizar ese valor. La inserción la hace correctamente y la actualización llegué a conseguir hacer lo que he dicho del pagineo, pero solo guardaba la primera página.

Comment: Como recomendacion separa el metodo Guardar en una clase digamos DatosJugadores esta clase solo tendra los metodos para interactuar con la base de datos en lugar de actual.m_ljcPlantillaJugadores[i].Guardar(); tendras un llamado   datosJugadores.ActualizarUsuario(nick,usuarioPrincipal) con esto le das una mayor claridad a tu codigo y puedes hacer un debug mas sencillo